# Call a delete page in a function

Tags: jquery

There`s a function in my page, which is to delete a row of a table:

```
$('#lista').on('click', '.menos', function () {
   if ($('#lista tbody').children('tr').length > 1) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
         $(':input[name^="preco"]').trigger("keyup");
         var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
         // i need to call a page deleteItem.php?id= trid
      }
  } 
  else 
  {
      alert("You must have at least one product.");
  }
});
```

Basically I need to call a delete page as soon as the delete button is pressed.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

PHP file:

```
include "conexao.php";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM itenspedido WHERE idItensPedido = '".$id."'");
```

Comment: look at [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[$.ajax(](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**) here:

```
var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "deleteItem.php",
    data: "id="+trid,
    success: function (data) {
        // Code 
    }
});
```

Comment: it makes sense but it's not working.. is there a way to see if ajax is calling as deleteItem?id=trid ?

Comment: I've already used `GET` method, so it'll automatically append the query string for you. Can you post your PHP code?